# How can I get an auto-generated file to recognize a method it created itself?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, css

I have a *.tt file (two, actually, but they are acting similarly, so I'll just talk about one).

I have them set just like another project, where they work fine. Their properties are set the same, such as:

```
CustomTool = TetxtTemplatingFilePreprocessor
```

When I select "Run Custom Tool", a corresponding *.cs file is created:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version: 10.0.0.0
//  
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But the project won't compile, because this code *in the auto-generated file* (FormTemplate.cs):

```
FormTemplate formTemplate = new FormTemplate(POST, this);
output.Write(formTemplate.TransformText());
```

...won't compile. The err is, "'QuizModule.QuizModuleWebPart.Templates.FormTemplate' does not contain a definition for 'TransformText' and no extension method 'TransformText' accepting a first argument of type 'QuizModule.QuizModuleWebPart.Templates.FormTemplate' could be found"

How can it generate the code, and then not be able to find a method it references? Actually, it *did* generate the method, and it is right there in FormTemplate.cs:

```
#line 1   
"C:\Projects\QuizModule_Test\QuizModule_Test\QuizModuleWebPart\Templates\FormTem
plate.tt"   

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating", "10.0.0.0")]
    public partial class FormTemplate : FormTemplateBase
    {
        {
        public virtual string TransformText()
            {
```

Why would it be that it cannot see its own method?

### UPDATE

This turned out to be one of those "my bads" that produces seemingly in[s]ane err msgs. What happened was, some of my namespaces were wrong - the code had been copied over verbatim from another project, and the namespaces had not been updated. Once those were rectified, the project compiled just fine.

Comment: Side note - consider flagging for moderator as "other - to close the question with bounty" - not much point for it to stay opened with bounty... At least put comment on top saying it is solved/ "closed" already, maybe even add update as answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agree, this just wasted 5 minutes of my time

Comment: I did flag it, right after Alexei made that comment.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - the way to say a question is solved is to post an answer and accept it. Not put it in the title or the body of the post itself.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - sorry. Looks like I got the wrong commenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CAUSE**

This turned out to be one of those "my bads" that produces seemingly in[s]ane err msgs.

**SOLUTION**

What happened was, some of my namespaces were wrong - the code had been copied over verbatim from another project, and the namespaces had not been updated. Once those were rectified, the project compiled just fine.